# How do I get webpack to rewrite image sources from pug?

Tags: webpack, pug-loader

I am writing an Angular 2 application and want to use pug for my templates. I am using webpack to build the solution.

If I just use

```
{
    test: /\.pug$/,
    loader: 'pug-html-loader' 
},
```

in the webpack config file, the URLs of the image files are not rewritten. So I tried to change the pug to

```
img(src=require('../../public/images/logo.png'))
```

but that gives this error:

```
Module build failed: TypeError: require is not a function
```

So, instead I'm trying the following webpack configuration:

```
{
    test: /\.pug$/,
    loader: 'html?attrs=img:src!pug-html-loader' 
},
```

But that gives this error:

```
ERROR in ./src/app/app.component.pug
Module not found: Error: Cannot resolve 'file' or 'directory' ./\"../../public/images/logo.png\" in /<app-path>/src/app
 @ ./src/app/app.component.pug 1:213-263
```

What is the correct/best way of solving this issue?

Comment: Using `html-loader` looks right to me. But it's unclear on what source you are trying to apply it: it needs not to contain `src=require(...)` anymore, just `src=../../public/images/logo.png`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out I was hitting [this bug in the pug-html-loader](https://github.com/willyelm/pug-html-loader/issues/4) package. By using a different version of this package, I made it work.

Answer (score 0):

As @andreypopp says, you do not need the `require()` in the pug. But also, you do need to set the pug-loader `exports` option to `false` so that it exports the raw generated html rather than a js module. Here's my config:

```
  {
    test: /\.pug$/,
    loaders: [
      // html loader gets webpack to process <img> src
      'html-loader',
      // requires pretty option otherwise some spacing between elements is lost
      'pug-html-loader?{"pretty":true,"exports":false}'
    ],
    include: [sourcePath]
  },
```